# Feasibility of playing an explorer in Wurm Online

Tags: wurm-online

I played Wurm about a year ago. It was a great game, but as I felt I'd be forced to relog when I finally got bored of it, to maintain my structures against decay, I quit. I have been contemplating playing without building anything, however I remember the game penalizing you heavily for hunger, food being hard to procure for beginners, tools taking time to make and player trade relying on high-quality items made with high skill levels and good materials.

Is playing a homeless vagrant feasible in Wurm, and if so, how does one go about accomplishing this with a new character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several options for playing a gypsy character.

1) I have a friend who gave up his deed, lives on his boat, and sails from village to village working on projects for people in return for donations (anything they can/want to donate, or even nothing at all). These places usually provide meals, a bed, and some social interaction. Some are grateful enough for his services such that, if they cannot afford much in coinage, will still offer tools, improvements to his current gear, and other services that benefit him. He gets a chance to see different parts of the game world and try out different skills without having any specific "obligations". If he wants to, he can take months-long absences from the game without any real penalties, and meantime meets many new faces and continually improves his skills.

2) There are villages who allow "casual" players, and often provide a home/food/safety for you so that you can just log in periodically and not have to worry about maintaining your own place. Be sure to check in advance though whether they mind "drop in, play, drop out" type players.

You CAN play a homeless vagrant, as you really don't 'need' high end tools or gear. The two biggest immediate needs, are food and safety. It helps a lot to at least have a fishing pole, a few pottery bowls, and the ability to make "fish stew" to keep from starving. Safety then becomes the next hurdle -- maybe consider doing some labor for someone in exchange for a rowboat (about 50c value; some places may have spares they would exchange for a player who replants trees, spindles cloth strings for their tailor, and other low-skill activities.) With a few exceptions (bears & crocodiles) most monsters won't enter water and you can flee to your boat if you encounter trouble. You can also just swim out a few tiles if you have no boat -- so maybe stick to waterfront areas. You can also find a place to build a simple 2x1 cabin, forgo crops/livestock and anything else requiring constant care, and with a little monthly maintenance work the shed should survive your periodic absences ok.

I happen to think my friend's "travelling laborer for hire" is a nice choice if you like moving around and meeting new people. At first, you will be limited in what help you can offer, but many players do have "easy but time consuming tasks" where they would be happy to barter food/tools/supplies for an hours work or so. As long as you don't get caught up in thinking you "need" much, you can get by with very few possesssions beyond your fishing pole and a few pottery bowls.